# Forge API "Urn is not in the proper format."

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

I'm using this endpoint..

projects/:project_id/folders/:folder_id/contents

...and getting back error 400 "Urn is not in the proper format." on data stored in EU servers. The endpoint works correctly for other project data (urn's containing wipprod) but returns this error on all urn's containing wipemea.

Is there a differend end point I should be using for data stored on EU servers or is there something I should be doing different with urn's containing wipemea?

Comment: **Does the projectId match the EMEA BIM360 Docs project?**
It is used to determine whether the request should go to US or EMEA servers.

If you have an `X-Request-Id` header from the 400 response, that would help narrow down the search. I found some 400's on EMEA yesterday, but none from a GetFolderContents request. (However, I found quite many with EMEA URNs on the US servers, leading to the described error.)

Comment: That was exactly the problem. There was a error in what I was passing in as the project id. Thanks!

Comment: thanks @SimonD., maybe you can post as an answer? We'll give you some Stackoverflow points :D

Answer (score 0):

Since that actually was the problem, I'm reposting [the comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53504518/forge-api-urn-is-not-in-the-proper-format?noredirect=1#comment93907373_53504518) as an answer:

**To access EMEA folders, items and versions (URN contains `wipemea`), the `projectId` must match the BIM 360 Document Management EMEA Project.**